# Change IOS Done Button Text

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

how can i change this default done button text ? [image]

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        QLPreviewController* cntr = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
        cntr.delegate = weakSelf;
        cntr.dataSource = weakSelf;

        if (callback) {
            callback(@[[NSNull null], array]);
        }
        UIViewController* root = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] rootViewController];
        [root presentViewController:cntr animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

Comment: Which class is your viewController? can you provide some details?

Comment: Hi @ReinierMelian, i actually create react-native method and dont have too much info about xcode. i think this QLPreviewController default set done button but dont know how can i change it.

Comment: Let me know if my answer in some way help you

Comment: @ReinierMelian, i am editing this lib https://github.com/philipphecht/react-native-doc-viewer/tree/master/ios but not success yet... i need to remove done button from openDoc method in M file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can make this work was using `self.navigationController.push` instead of `self.present` to show the `QLPreviewController` you need also subclass `QLPreviewController` and make few modifications

```
#import "CustomPreviewViewController.h"

@implementation CustomPreviewViewController

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.navigationItem setHidesBackButton:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftItemsSupplementBackButton:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"none" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil]];
}

@end
```

Hope this helps